# Squarespace OM Template - Resizing Banner Image Doesn't Work

Tags: squarespace

When I try to resize the Om Template's banner image through the edit tool for Banner/Thumbnail Image, the changes don't seem to take. How can I resize the banner image?

Comment: This is not a coding issue if no code is provided. If you are looking for theme support please contact SquareSpace, if you are looking for someone to write a custom code for you please hire a developer. If you are trying to fix an issue show us what have you tried ( via code ) and we can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the OM template's header image, and adding an image block to the top of the page content which allowed me to upload an image sized to my requirements without changing it.